# Python SpeedUp: reading data from mongodb slow

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a scraper dumping data into mongodb, and my other module trying to retrieve the data from mongodb, but its very slow as per the line profile

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   607                                               @profile
   608                                               def get_item_iterator(self):
   609                                                   """
   610                                                   build a generator from the item collection
   611                                                   """
   612         1            1      1.0      0.4          query = {'token': self.token}
   613                                                   # for item in self.collection.find(query):
   614                                                   #     yield item
   615                                                   # return (item for item in self.collection.find(query))
   616         1          263    263.0     98.9          items_cur=self.collection.find(query)
   617         1            2      2.0      0.8          return items_cur

Total time: 0.168562 s
File: optim_id.py
Function: Identify at line 618

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   618                                               @profile
   619                                               def Identify(self):
   620                                                   """
   621                                                   identify CTAs
   622                                                   """
   623         1            2      2.0      0.0          try:
   624         1            1      1.0      0.0              flag=0
   625         1          280    280.0      0.2              items_cur=self.get_item_iterator()
   626       112       158137   1411.9     93.8              for item in items_cur:
   627       111          218      2.0      0.1                  if flag==0:
```

so you can see per hit time is huge, how can i reduce this significantly.
i hear list comprehension is faster than for loop, that i tried as well but without any success.

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   607                                               @profile
   608                                               def get_item_iterator(self):
   609                                                   """
   610                                                   build a generator from the item collection
   611                                                   """
   612         1            2      2.0      0.6          query = {'token': self.token}
   613                                                   # for item in self.collection.find(query):
   614                                                   #     yield item
   615         1          310    310.0     99.4          return (item for item in self.collection.find(query))

Total time: 0.150235 s
File: optim_id.py
Function: Identify at line 616

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
   616                                               @profile
   617                                               def Identify(self):
   618                                                   """
   619                                                   identify CTAs
   620                                                   """
   621         1            2      2.0      0.0          try:
   622         1          328    328.0      0.2              item_list=self.get_item_iterator()
   623         1       139896 139896.0     93.1              item_record=item_list.next()
```

my mongodb statistics:

```
db.stats()
{
    "db" : "scrapy_database",
    "collections" : 102,
    "objects" : 167007,
    "avgObjSize" : 1091.1401797529445,
    "dataSize" : 182228048,
    "storageSize" : 310439936,
    "numExtents" : 374,
    "indexes" : 100,
    "indexSize" : 6115648,
    "fileSize" : 469762048,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "extentFreeList" : {
        "num" : 4,
        "totalSize" : 6029312
    },
    "dataFileVersion" : {
        "major" : 4,
        "minor" : 22
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
> collection=db['scraped_rawdata']
scrapy_database.scraped_rawdata
> collection.stats()
{
    "ns" : "scrapy_database.scraped_rawdata",
    "count" : 100451,
    "size" : 121793232,
    "avgObjSize" : 1212,
    "numExtents" : 13,
    "storageSize" : 168075264,
    "lastExtentSize" : 46333952,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "paddingFactorNote" : "paddingFactor is unused and unmaintained in 3.0. It remains hard coded to 1.0 for compatibility only.",
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "capped" : false,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 3270400,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 3270400
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

but i am querying items which is in 111 in total

```
> collection.find({"token":"9a9ec6086bb4a4a7ae8cd44b909b139930e561c3"}).count()
111
```

Comment: What is the size of the database? Do you use indexes for your collections?

Comment: Just because you are only returning 111 items does not mean there is not a lot of work being done to get there. There is notably "no index" on the "token" property, and that means a "collection scan" in order to retrieve the results. So yes, this is working through over 100,000 entries to find the 111 you want. Add an index to "token". You also might consider storing the "binary" representation of that rather than a "hex" string. Unless you want to use a "substring" of that value for a search, then the binary form will take less space and memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to increase the `bath_size` of your query, it appears that every item requires hit to database. Also add index for the `token` field.

Comment: Is it `cursor.batchSize()` you are referning to?

Comment: Yes, that looks to be the right function to set it in python driver